# Windows driver in wine

Tags: windows, printing, driver, wine

I have a printer in my job, Brother HL-2240D, and i need somre driver for linux to get the status information for that (toner level, empty paper, ...).

Actualy I use a driver for linux and I print ok, but this driver dont't get me the status for the printer. Windows driver is the only driver who get the status.

I have found a few days, but it doesn't exist, so I have an idea, install the windows driver in Wine. Can anybody help me to install this drivers in wine?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can install _driver_ through wine and expect it to work seamlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are is some weird printer related stuff to wine but I doubt you'll be able to get status working like you hoped. My advice is to either dual boot with windows (or have a separate machine running windows) or even run a virtual machine on your linux pc and have windows running in that. You could then use the virtual version of windows to connect to the printer and receive the printer status stuff with the windows driver and tools.

Comment: thanks. finally I make a little driver to solve this. I use a windows sniffer to know how it run, and then i use libusb in C to do similar functionality. Certainly in wine I can't install that driver.